# Filtering and Then Summing Groupby Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I want to find the sum of all the survived values in the Pandas data series when the 'Fare' is >100. The Panda data series was created using the `.groupby('Fare')`.

```
 Name: Survived, dtype: int64
Fare
0.0000      1
4.0125      0
5.0000      0
6.2375      0
6.4375      0
6.4500      0
6.4958      0
6.7500      0
6.8583      0
6.9500      0
6.9750      1
7.0458      0
7.0500      0
7.0542      0
7.1250      0
7.1417      1
7.2250      3
7.2292      4
7.2500      1
7.3125      0
7.4958      1
7.5208      0
7.5500      1
7.6292      0
7.6500      1
7.7250      0
7.7292      0
7.7333      2
7.7375      1
7.7417      0
           ..
80.0000     2
81.8583     1
82.1708     1
83.1583     3
83.4750     1
86.5000     3
89.1042     2
90.0000     3
91.0792     2
93.5000     2
106.4250    1
108.9000    1
110.8833    3
113.2750    2
120.0000    4
133.6500    2
134.5000    2
135.6333    2
146.5208    2
151.5500    2
153.4625    2
164.8667    2
211.3375    3
211.5000    0
221.7792    0
227.5250    3
247.5208    1
262.3750    2
263.0000    2
512.3292    3
```

I tried using this `fare_df.loc[fare_df.index >100, fare_df[:]].sum()` but I get the error:

```
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the `sum()` you're looking for:

```
fare_df[fare_df.Fare > 100]['Survived'].sum()
```